# React-Mapbox-GL keeps refreshing on state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mapbox

I have the following simple React Component using the react-mapbox-gl wrapper. So far, it's great, however I find a small annoyance when trying to update state, using the useState hook.

```
    function Location(props) {
       const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);
       const [markerBlock, setMarkerBlock] = useState(false)
      const {payload} = useContext(MarkerContext);
      const [latlong, setLatlong] = useState(null);


      console.log(payload);

        const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
            accessToken:
              'tokenHiddenforstackoverflow',

          });

          const getLatlng = (map, event) => {

              setLatlong(event.lngLat);
          }


        return (
            <>
    <Map
      style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9"
      containerStyle={{
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100%'
      }}
      onClick={getLatlng}
      center={[18.432723671572944, -33.926210020024826]}
    >
    <ZoomControl />

    </Map>

            </>

        );
    }

    export default Location;
```

Whenever I update the LatLong state, the mapbox background turns black and the whole map reloads. Not sure if a coding / structural error or a bug from Mapbox. I tried restructuring this into smaller components as well, but no difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

This is expected behavior since with every state change, `ReactMapboxGl` gets re-created. One solution (to prevent map API reload and maps re-render) would be to create a *single* instance of `ReactMapboxGl` *outside* of `Location` function:

```
//create a single instance of WebGl Mapbox map   
const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken:
    "--your token goes here--"
});


function Location(props) {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (map, event) => {
    setPosition([event.lngLat.lat, event.lngLat.lng]);
  };

  return (
    <Map
      style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9"
      containerStyle={{
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%"
      }}
      onClick={handleClick}
      center={[18.432723671572944, -33.926210020024826]}
    ></Map>
  );
}

export default Location;
```